# use of NSNumberFormatter in iphone

Tags: iphone

i want to do padding of characters by using nsnumberformatter.
   For Example. if string's value is 1 then it should get converted to 1.0.0.
     and  if string value is 1.2 then it should get converted to 1.2.0

please help if any one know this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use NSNumberFormatter for this ? If you convert the string to a float value:

```
NSString *string = @"1.2";
float num = [string floatValue];
```

You can use the NSString -stringWithFormat: method to print the number as you see fit:

```
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.1f.0", num];
```

newString would now be "1.2.0"

Answer (score 0):

"1.2.0" isn't a number, so NSNumberFormatter probably isn't the class you want. Instead, [create your own NSFormatter subclass](http://tinyurl.com/3zzq2xn) that does the formatting you want.